# VB Script to select a dropdown value, without knowing it's technical ID

Tags: vbscript

I need to create a vb Script which would select a value from a drop down selection box.
Problem is I just know the name of the window; no technical ID's of the window or dropdown  is known.
I can only bring it in front through "AppActivate".
I have also tried using "SendKeys", but it is not an editable drop down menu, so simply entering the value does not help.

Could you please help.

Regards,
Suyash Rathi.

Comment: You can't select a particular value from a particular dropdown list with zero knowledge about the thing. Is the control in a web page or an application? Is it the only dropdown list or are there others? Any other distinguishing features?

Answer (score 3):

Too much unknown staffs, but here is something to get started.

Lets say we have this code in our hmtl page:

```
<select>
  <option value="A">Volvo</option>
  <option value="B">Saab</option>
  <option value="C">BMW</option>
  <option value="D" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

In .vbs script add:

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://your_target_url_here.com/"

Do
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy

' get first HTMLSelectElement object:
Set e = Document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)

' just for undestanding...
MsgBox e.Options(e.selectedIndex).Value '-> "D"
MsgBox e.Options(e.selectedIndex).Text  '-> "Audi"

' select first option:
e.selectedIndex = 0
```